# JSON Blog Example

Tags: json, data-structures, structure

I'm new to JSON and don't really understand how to structure data in JSON format. If someone can show me an example for a blog, I will be able to understand it better. So far I've  got

```
{
    "blog" : {
        "id": "3423232",
        "user" : {
            "id": "23143"
            "name": "Jimmy Carter",
            "username": "JimmyC"
        },
        "title": "Being me",
        "description": "How to be a president",
        "modified": "2009-03-17T03:53:36Z",
        "published": true,
        "tags": ["president", "usa", "john", "quincy", "adams"]
    }
}
```

But what if I wanted to find all the blogs posted by user "JimmyC" or blogs with tags "usa", how do I go about querying it. Is there a better way to structure the data in JSON so its easier to query it?

Comment: JSON doesn't define a query language. The data is typically parsed and converted to native datatypes of a programming language and then use the tools the programming language provides to traverse / search the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a way to structurate the data in the same way as xml but simplier and lighter because of its simple syntax.
If you wan't to retrieve the data from the JSON, you'll have to use a langage and its library.

For exemple, if you're working with javascript, use the JSON library to retrieve the data:

```
var json = '{"foo":12345,"count":1}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.foo);
```

If you're working with PHP

```
$json = '{"foo": 12345,"count":1}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo'};
```

And so on... If you need more help, say us what langage you're using and what doesn't work with your code.